# C++ QT library to plot a vector

Tags: c++, qt, graph

Good evening everyone, I'll explain my problem:
I would like to use the qt library for c ++ in such a way as to be able to represent a vector (let's assume integers) as a bar chart. Obviously the size of the bar will be determined by the content of the value within the i-th element of the vector.

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtcharts-barchart-example.html

```
std::vector<int> v{ 10, 20, 30 }; 
QBarSet *set0 = new QBarSet("vector");
*set0 << v[0] << v[1] << v[2];
QBarSeries *series = new QBarSeries();
series->append(set0);
QChart *chart = new QChart();
chart->addSeries(series);
```

A possible idea could be to declare a vector and insert it inside a qbarset and then insert it in a series and load it on the graph. Is it possible to make sure that if the values ​​of the vector change, the plot is updated according to their content?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The `QBarSet *set0` doesn't share the storage of data in `std::vector<int> v;`. (Instead, the values are copied.) Hence, changes in `v` won't have effect at all. You have to change the contents of `set0`, at least. To detect changes in `v` (e.g. per signal is IMHO impossible). Instead, you could wrap/hide `std::vector<int> v;` in an object which emits a signal whenever data is written to `v` (using a wrapper class function). This signal may then connected to a slot which forces the necessary update of the associated `QBarSet`.

Comment: Concerning modification of a `QBarSet`, I have a much better feeling. It provides signals [void QBarSet::valueChanged(int index)](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qbarset.html#valueChanged), [void QBarSet::valuesAdded(int index, int count)](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qbarset.html#valuesAdded), [void QBarSet::valuesRemoved(int index, int count)](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qbarset.html#valuesRemoved). However, I must admit that I've no personal experience with `QChart` and company.